# Assertion Failed when tapping the screen too much

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am developing a game that throws bullets to the direction of tap. But when I tap too much/multiple times in the center of the player, I get the following error:

```
Runtime error
    assertion failed!
    stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'assert'
        ?: in function '?'
        ?: in function '_initTween'
        ?: in function 'to'
        /Users/User/Desktop/MD/screen1.lua:61: in function </Users/User/Desktop/MD/screen1.lua:31>
        ?: in function <?:221>
```

But when I tap slowly, it is not throwing the error. Here is the line 61 of screen1.lua:

```
bullet.trans = transition.to(bullet, { time=distance/bulletSpeed, y=farY, x=farX, onComplete=nil})
```

Thanks for all the help!

EDIT:
After adding this line:

```
print("Values for transition: ", bullet, distance, bulletSpeed, farY, farX)
```

This is the result:
[image]

Distance and fary are both Nan.

Comment: It is hard to say how solve your problem . Maybe provide code from tap listener.

Comment: Well, the message on the stack says some assertion fails in function `?` which is called from  `_initTween` which is called from `to`. You'd better check documentation or source on `to` and `_initTween` at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to debug a problem like this:

As a first step towards solving this problem, I suggest you print the value of the variables involved in the call to `transition.to()` before the call:

```
print("Values for transition: ", bullet, distance, bulletSpeed, farY, farX)
```

It's possible something is not being set/initialized properly.  It will also reveal if and when you are trying to call a transition on a `nil` object.

UPDATE:

So further investigation shows that at some point you are trying to pass `NaN` (From the manual: "(Not a Number is a special value used to represent undefined or unrepresentable numerical results, such as 0/0.)") as arguments to `transition.to` and it objects to this.  You should look at your assumptions when you compute `distance` and `farY`.  Could you be dividing by zero or taking the square root of a negative number somewhere?

Comment: I test different combination of variables involved for example I used nil as object to transition. No error come up. I use latest stable version of  Corona Simulator (2017.3068).

Comment: I updated my question with the print line. Please see the result.

Comment: @JaysonTamayo That "invalid number argument" error is very helpful.  See the update to my answer.

Comment: I get the same error message when I use 0/0 for `x` or `y`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that when you are tapping very fast you at some point accidentally hit the location that you are calculating distance from. Something in your distance algorithm causes its maths to fail and it spits out `NaN` (which is basically a divide by zero or placeholder for other mathematical problems).

Check for NaN in the distance calculation and replace it with 0. Better still, improve the calculation. You can use a library I wrote - look for the `lengthOf` function:

https://gist.github.com/HoraceBury/9431861